# Make all paths relative for a blend file via python

Tags: python, path

I have a bunch of blend files, each in their own directory with supported files wherever necessary. I want to configure all the blend files to use relative paths. I can open each of them and do `File > Externel Data > Make all paths relative`. But since I've a lot of blend files, this is time consuming. Is it possible to do this via python script?

Comment: Are they all in one directory or something?

Comment: No, they're in different directory. But I can run the same python script for each blend file. That, I've got it covered. I need to know how to set this setting via python for a single blend file.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.file.html?highlight=make%20paths%20external#bpy.ops.file.make_paths_relative

Comment: Thanks! I think that will work. I'll try it. I'm new to blender. How can I search for such things? i.e. how to do some things via python which I know how to do in GUI. I tried looking at blender python documentation, but I couldn't make head or tail out of it

Comment: In _Preferences > Interface_, turn on _Python Tooltips_. It will show you what to call in Python in the tooltip when you hover over a button.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will make all paths relative and then save

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.file.make_paths_relative()
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

You can run this from the shell like this. This should make all paths in `file.blend` relative

```
blender --background file.blend --python-expr 'import bpy;bpy.ops.file.make_paths_relative();bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()'
```